# Why a non weakly-continuous operator hasn't got a corresponding self-adjoint operator?

Tags: operator-theory, weak-convergence

I am reading a paper about [Polymer Quantum Mechanics](https://arxiv.org/abs/0704.0007) and I stumbled over a sentence that, no matter how much I think about it, I cannot understand. Its understanding is not vital to the global comprehension of the paper but nevertheless, after all the time I have spent searching, I would like to finally grasp it.

This is the obscure passage:

> [...] In our case, since the operator
>   $$ \hat { V } (\mu)=e^{i\mu\hat{p}/h}  $$
>   is not weakly continuous in $\mu$ in the polymeric representation, the corresponding would-be self-adjoint momentum operator $\hat{p}$ does not exist. [...]

$\hat { V }$ would be one half of the base of the the Weyl algebra generated by exponentiation of the two operators $ \hat { q } $ e  $ \hat { p } $. The base can be written as:
$$ \hat { V } (\mu)=e^{i\mu\hat{p}/h} \quad \quad ; \quad \quad  \hat { U } (\nu)=e^{i\nu\hat{q}/h} $$

My question is: in the case of operators on an Hilbert space (members of the Weyl Algebra as in this case), **what is a weakly continuous operator and why, if an operator isn't such, the corresponding self-adjoint $\hat{p}$ doesn't exist?**

I would be more than satisfied even if, instead of a full fledged answer, you could at least provide me with some literature references (maybe a book?) that a student writing his Master's Degree thesis in Physics can tackle and get a rough answer in a matter of some hours/days.

Thank you in advance for any help.